# MySql: Show columns but exclude everything except the field names

Tags: mysql

I'd like to pull a table's field names from MySql into python, and I know that

```
'show columns from project'
```

will work. And I've read that you can add 'WHERE ...' to restrict it to just certain fields. But I can't find an example of how to return just the names of the columns, and not Type, Key, Null, Extra information.

What is the matching criteria to pull all field names for columns and none of the other description stuff?

Comment: Related, if it's of interest, I wrote a *Describe All Tables* in [this Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38679580).

Answer (score 97, accepted):

```
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE  table_name = 'your_table'
   AND table_schema = 'database_name'
```

Comment: Wonderful! I tested on phpMyAdmin on two servers. But there is only one information_schema database on each server, and potentially multiple tables in different databases on the save server that have the same table name. How does it know which list of table columns to pull in that case?

Comment: Check out the `table_schema` column

Comment: For me it is working also without "AND table_schema = 'database_name'"

Comment: FYI, if you want to list the columns in the order they appear on the table, add `ORDER BY ordinal_position` to the query

Answer (score 21):

Although it looks more elegant, you don't need awk for this.
MySQL's information_schema.columns table has the info you need.

-- DESCRIBE THE HECK OUT OF THE ENTIRE 'table_name' table in the 'database_name' database

```
SHOW COLUMNS
FROM database_name.table_name ;
```

-- SHOW JUST THE COLUMN NAMES for 'table_name' table in the 'database_name' database.

```
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'database_name'
AND table_name = 'table_name' ;
```

Answer (score 3):

Pipe the answer to awk:

```
SHOW columns FROM project; | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can query MySQL's `information_schema` database directly for the fieldnames:

```
select distinct(COLUMN_NAME) from information_schema.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='posts';
```

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is a comma-delimited list (Not very Python literate, but that's mostly what you'd want in PHP and Perl) GROUP_CONCAT is your friend:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column_name) FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='your-table-name-here' GROUP BY TABLE_NAME ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
```

If you need them quoted this gives you all EXCEPT the outermost quotes:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column_name SEPARATOR '","') FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='your-table-name-here' GROUP BY TABLE_NAME ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
```

Answer (score -4):

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM `table_name`
```

This MySQL query will work best, it will show all fields of a MySQL table.