# MySQL, get (just) column names and write them to a file?

Tags: mysql, metadata, database-schema

I would like to get more or less what is discussed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165195/mysql-query-to-get-column-names).

What more? I would like to redirect the output to a file.

What less? The `SHOW columns FROM your-table;` actually returns a lot of stuff. In addition to column names it also shows i.e. type.

Ideally, in the end, I would like a plain text file listing one column name per line.

Comment: Did you read the manual of your mysql command line client? There is an option to output to a file.. There is also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html

Comment: What's wrong with the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4165253/1015327?

Comment: Something like `"C:\mysql-5.6.17-winx64\bin\mysql" -h localhost -uuser -ppassword -e"use db_my_db; select * from my_view;" >> test.txt` helps.

Comment: May be you are looking for [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525970/mysql-show-columns-but-exclude-everything-except-the-field-names)